# Why does overload of template and non-template function with the "same signature" call the non-template function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading

I have this code:

```
template<
    class T = const int &
> void f(T) {}

void f(const int &) {}

int main() {
   f(0);
}
```

Why does it call the second one instead of first? I would think of them as being the same but they're clearly not as I do not get a redefinition error.

Comment: http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f9aac9532f21077433027f9ae341417b calls number 2 here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because the second overload is not a template.

When a template function and a non-template function are both viable for resolving a function call, the non-template function is selected.

From Paragraph 13.3.3/1 of the C++ 11 Standard:

> [...] Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a **better function** than another viable function F2 if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), **and then [...] F1 is a non-template function and F2 is a function template specialization** [...]

Answer (score 9):

One is a template and the other is not, they are definitely not the same.

Overload resolution is designed to prefer a non-template over a templated function, everything else being equal.