# Why am i getting 2 as an output?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
void f(T &i)
{
    cout<<"1";
}
void f(const int&i)
{
    cout<<"2";
}
int main()
{
    f(7);
}
```

I have used a template function and a normal function. But the function with const int argument is executing when called. Why is that so?

Comment: The function template doesn't come into play because 7 cannot bind to a non-const reference.

Comment: Also relevant, because even if the signature was `void f(T i)` and `void f(const int& i)`, the output would still be `2`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666219/why-does-overload-of-template-and-non-template-function-with-the-same-signature

Comment: What if i give const T&i

Comment: Because 7 is a literal, so a constant?

Comment: RE: *"What if i give const T&i "* - SO is not a tutoring site. And besides, learning C++ via SO isn't a good way to go about it. Your questions indicate you haven't gotten through the basics of it yet. I suggest you browse our [community curated book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), and pick a good beginner book from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does overload of template and non-template function with the "same signature" call the non-template function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666219/why-does-overload-of-template-and-non-template-function-with-the-same-signature)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your code is compiling, depend on type of arguments and number of argument, compiler will find the most related function to response your function call `f(7)` before move to `Template` functions. In this case, the most related function is `void f(const int&i)` so you got 2 as an output.